# Scroll content size not working in viewDidLayoutSubviews

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

Am using xib to design my view using auto layout.Run time I want to change the content size of my scrollview in viewDidLayoutSubviews method but its not working.On orientation change the code written inside viewDidLayoutSubviews works but on load its not working.Please advice what could be the issue?

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{

        scroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scroll.frame.size.width, attBtn.frame.origin.y+attBtn.frame.size.height+40);//atnBtn is added programatically


}
```

Comment: this method call `[self setneeddisplay];`

Answer (score 0):

Usually when you want to have a view redraw you should call:

`[self setNeedsDisplay: YES];`

Granted I have never build on iOS, on OSX this code works every time. Also, for example, if you want your delegate to call a redraw for a view named someView:

`[someView setNeedsDisplay: YES];`